Why is openapi-generator using unknown imports
Im developing an api to show the results of a query in elasticsearch and im getting some imports error.
Example of result:
{
  "took": 136,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 4,
    "successful": 4,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 10.896778,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "wikipedia",
        "_id": "25682",
        "_score": 10.896778,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Random binary tree",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree",
          "content": "Random binary tree In computer science and probability theory, a random binary tree is a binary tree selected at random from some probability distribution on binary trees. Two different distributions are commonly used: binary trees formed by inserting nodes one at a time according to a random permutation, and binary trees chosen from a uniform discrete distribution in which all distinct trees are equally likely. It is also possible to form other distributions, for instance by repeated splitting.",
          "dt_creation": "2015-12-19",
          "reading_time": 11
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "wikipedia",
        "_id": "3718",
        "_score": 10.62151,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Treap",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap",
          "content": "In computer science, the treap and the randomized binary search tree are two closely related forms of binary search tree data structures that maintain a dynamic set of ordered keys and allow binary searches among the keys. After any sequence of insertions and deletions of keys, the shape of the tree is a random variable with the same probability distribution as a random binary tree; in particular, with high probability its height is proportional to the logarithm of the number of keys, so that ea",
          "dt_creation": "2019-12-25",
          "reading_time": 12
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "wikipedia",
        "_id": "36690",
        "_score": 8.173512,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Janson inequality",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janson_inequality",
          "content": """In the mathematical theory of probability, Janson's inequality is a collection of related inequalities giving an exponential bound on the probability of many related events happening simultaneously by their pairwise dependence. Informally Janson's inequality involves taking a sample of many independent random binary variables, and a set of subsets of those variables and bounding the probability that the sample will contain any of those subsets by their pairwise correlation. Statement Let <som1>\""",
          "dt_creation": "2015-07-08",
          "reading_time": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "suggest": {
    "my-suggestion": [
      {
        "text": "random",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 10,
        "options": []
      },
      {
        "text": "binar",
        "offset": 11,
        "length": 5,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "binari",
            "score": 0.8,
            "freq": 390
          },
          {
            "text": "benar",
            "score": 0.8,
            "freq": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "tree",
        "offset": 17,
        "length": 4,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  }
}

And i have the following api.yml
openapi: '3.0.0'
info:
  version: '1.0.0'
  title: 'Sample API'
  description: Initial example to submit Elasticsearch queries

paths:
  /search:
    get:
      summary: 'Submits a query to Elasticsearch'
      operationId: search
      tags:
        - search
      parameters:
        - name: query
          in: query
          description: Query to be submitted
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Result'
        500:
          description: Unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
components:
  schemas:
    Result:
      type: object
      properties:
        Hits:
          type: object
          properties:
            title:
              type: string
            url:
              type: string
            abs:
              type: string
            dt_creation:
              type: string
        suggest:
          type: string
    Error:
      type: object
      required:
        - message
      properties:
        message:
          description: A human readable error message
          type: string

When i run, i got this type of error:
-java: package com.google.gson does not exist
This package is auto generated, so i dont know what is going on
Please, help me!

I assume you use gradle and intellij? If so, did you try to write "gradle clean build" on the top left corner on Gradle?

I use maven and tried "mvn clean" and after "mvn install" to build the project, but ive got this error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project search: Compilation failure
[ERROR] [path]/SearchService.java:[31,50] package org.openapitools.client.model does not exist
[ERROR]
